# Adding css in rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a simple rails app and in the application.html.erb file I created a Bootstrap navbar inside the body.

I realised that when I put any content in index.html.erb (the home page), the navbar blocks the content. So I am going to add a padding to the 'body' element in 'application.html.erb' i.e., the common layout file.

But when I add the padding to 'home.scss', it doesn't work. The file says:

// Place all the styles related to the home controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.

So by right, this body style should be reflected in the navbar, but it doesn't. Where should I be including the style css for the common layout (application.html.erb)?

- also, for other pages (ex. index.html.erb), 1) How do I link up the css file (do I do it like any other html file) and 2) Where do I edit the css?

I've browsed over 20 resources but I don't seem to be able to find a good explanation.

**+ Fixed:**

My css file was named 'application.scss.css' . When I renamed it to 'application.css.scss', it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the code for your line of css?

Comment: add the content of your `application.css` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1.
Checked out Your GEmfile.

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
bundle install
```

This gems are Both Css and Bootstrap.
Step 2.
    cd /app/assets/stylesheets
    Rename the file Application.css - To- Application.scss
  then run your code